# What determines the rotation direction in a $2$ D Dynamical system?

Tags: dynamical-systems, graphing-functions

Say we have a non linear system $\dot{x}=f(x)$ and we linearise this around an equilibrium point $x_0$, to obtain the linear sytem: $\dot{x}=Df(x_0)\cdot x$.

Where $Df(x_0)$ is the jacobian (and in this case a $2\times 2$ matrix).

We find the eigenvalues, and for example say we have $\lambda_{1,2}=2\pm i$, so the  equilibrium point is unstable ($Re(\lambda_{1,2})=2\gt 0$).

When we wish to sketch the dynamics, I realise that the "sketch" will be a spiral spinning out of $x_0$, but what determines the direction of the spin?

i.e. anticlockwise or clockwise.

Thanks!

Comment: Plug some points into the original system to find the direction of the vector field at a point and sketch from there, I think. 

Sorry to sidetrack, but could I ask how your interview went for the doctoral program? I have an interview for a similar scheme at Imperial/Reading in a couple of weeks and have no idea what to expect!

Comment: @BritMiller, Thanks! it went well, I got in :) for me it was quite conversational, they just asked me about my interests and the work I had done. There is a chance that they will ask you to do some maths, is this the MPECDT you are applying for?

Comment: Congratulations - you must be over the moon! Yes, that's the one. I am most worried about the maths they might ask me to do. I've probably graduated top of my uni, but it's not great (UWE) and I'm not confident at all. Did the comment answer your question by the way, I didn't want to answer and comment at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the eigenvalues are conjugate nonreal complex numbers, the off-diagonal coefficients $b$ and $c$ of the Jacobian matrix $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\end{pmatrix}$ have opposite signs. If $c\gt0$ (and $b\lt0$), the solutions close to $x_0$ are going anticlockwise. If $b\gt0$ (and $c\lt0$), the solutions close to $x_0$ are going clockwise.